# what do referencefield store in mongoengine

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine

What do `ReferenceField` stores. I mean does it store ObjectID 
(or in my case `user_id`, as it is `primary_key` for User model). How can I access all the attributes of User model through unit_user as we do with the Foreignkey in Django

```
class User(Document):
  user_id              = IntField(primary_key=True)
  user_name            = StringField(max_length=100)
  user_email           = EmailField()

class MasterUnit(Document):
  unit_id             = IntField(primary_key=True)
  unit_name           = StringField(max_length=100)
  unit_user           = ReferenceField('User')
```

I am using POST method for posting data through my api:

```
class MasterUnitList(View):
  def get(self, request):
      masterunit = MasterUnit.objects.all().to_json()
      data = json.loads(masterunit)
      return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

  def post(self, request):
      data = json.loads(request.body)
      masterunit = MasterUnit(**data)
      masterunit.save()
      return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

My urls.py is

```
path('api/unit', MasterUnitList.as_view(), name='MasterUnitList'),
path('api/unit/<int:pk>', MasterUnitDetail.as_view(), name='MasterUnitDetail'),
```

I am using httpie

```
http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/unit unit_id=1 unit_name="Nokia" unit_user="?"
```

What do I pass in `unit_user` field?

Comment: the id of the user

Comment: The POST data is stored in `self.request.POST`.